# RequireJS and Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, laravel, requirejs, laravel-4

I'm trying to user require js and laravel to manage the assets directory.
I put the require.js file in assets/js directory, and the main.js too.
the main.js contains -

```
require.config({
    baseURL: '',
    paths: {
        userPreview: 'userPreview.js'
    }
})
```

the userPreview.js file is located also in assets/js.
So actually it looks like this -

assets /
    js /
      require.js
      main.js
      userPreview.js

in my php file I wrote -

```
<script data-main="assets/js/main" src="assets/js/require.js"></script>
```

but I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: UserPreview is not defined"!

The require.js file and the main.js file are both loaded (Checked in Google Developers Tool).

What is wrong?

Comment: Where is this error coming from? Browser console? If yes, then perhaps you have a type somewhere in your js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paths` object expects the values to not have an extension. So you'd want it to look like this:

```
userPreview: 'userPreview`
```

However you could accomplish the same thing by simply removing the `paths` object from the require config as `userPreview.js` is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like:

```
paths: {
  userPreview: './userPreview'
}
```